# Fourier series converges

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Suppose $S_N(x)$ is the Fourier series of $f(x)$, a continuous function.

Now, I've understood that if $S_N(x)$ converges uniformly to some $g(x)$ then is must be that $f\equiv g$.

- What about the case where $S_N(x)$ converges pointwise to $g(x)$?
- In which cases $g \not\equiv f$?

Comment: As $f$ is continuous, it is square-integrable. So, by Parseval's Theorem, $S_N \rightarrow f$ in the $L^2$ sense. Some measure-theoretic results say that if a sequence of functions converge in $L^2$, then there is a subsequence converging almost everywhere. So, $g \equiv f$ a.e.

Comment: Could you help me figure out this statement: "Since there's an $L_2$ convergence, then $S_N(f)\to g$ and $\|f-g\|=0$, but here both $f$ and $g$ are continuous and therefore $f\equiv g$".

Comment: @JoãoRamos : So is there a case where $f$ is continuous and the almost-everywhere convergence is not everywhere?  To complete the answer, one should either exhibit such a case or show there isn't any. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, Baire's Category Theorem tells us that for some not that nice continuous functions, we may have the Fourier Series diverging at a point - or even at a dense set of points. This shows that Fourier Series might not converge at some points.

Comment: When you say $f$ is continuous, you did not say $f$ is periodic. Are you assuming $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic?

Comment: @MichaelHardy :  The function  f in my article at   https://037598a680dc5e00a4d1feafd699642badaa7a8c.googledrive.com/host/0B4HffVs7117IbmZ2OTdKSVBZLVk/Fourier%20Series/Counter%20example%20to%20Riemann%20Lebesgue%20Lemma.pdf is such an example.  By the localization principle, the Fourier series of  f at x converges to  f(x) for x not equal to 0 but diverges at x = 0.

Comment: @zhw : I would probably construe the question as meaning a function that is continuous on the domain $\mathbb R/p$, i.e. reals modulo $p$, for some $p>0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $f$ is continuous and $2\pi$-periodic. Then if $S_N$ converges pointwise to some $g$ everywhere, we have $g\equiv f.$ Proof: Recall the result of Fejér: Set

$$F_N(x) = \frac{S_1(x)+ \cdots + S_N(x)}{N}.$$

(So the $F_N$'s are the Cesàro means of the sequence of partial sums of the Fourier series of $f.$) Fejér's theorem says that $F_N \to f$ uniformly on $\mathbb {R}.$

But of course for any fixed $x,$ if $S_N(x)\to L$ then $F_N(x)\to L.$ Since $F_N(x) \to f(x)$ everywhere, we have the result.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks to Daniel Fischer for appropriate accent marks.